# Change directory access control for common application data folder failed

Tags: c#, windows-vista

Here is my code, and I tried the same code for file access control, it works well.
but doesn't work for common application data on Vista.

```
private static void GrantEveryoneFullControlRight(string directory)
{
  try
  {
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    DirectorySecurity ds = dirInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);

    FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
                                "Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
                                AccessControlType.Allow);

    ds.AddAccessRule(rule);
    dirInfo.SetAccessControl(ds);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     // Logger.WriteLog(LogType.Error, ex.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? Does the user running the application have permissions to change the permissions on the target directory?

Comment: no exception. of course, i used administrator user to do it.